# Making QCompleter complete every word

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

PyQt5 I'm trying to make an autocompleter, which doesn't stop after the first space. It should start again for the next word, something like this:

```
completer = QCompleter()
completer.setCaseSensitivity(1)
textbox.setCompleter(completer)
model = QStringListModel()
model.setStringList(["How", "are", "you", "I", "am", "fine"])
completer.setModel(model)
```

but when I type `How a`, it should suggest `are` instead of nothing which would result in `How are` and be ready for the next word to be typed in.

Comment: With the duplicate answer, just use spaces instead of commas.

Comment: It shouldn't only suggest for `How are` but also for `How am` theoretically and all the other possiblie combinations of the words included in the list.